# test statistics

Tags: statistics

Let $X1$ and $X2$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $(0,\theta)$. Consider the two tests with critical regions $C1$ and $C2$ given by

$$C1 =\{(x1,x2)\ \mid \ x1 +x2 \ge 1\}$$

$$C2 = \{(x1, x2) \ \mid \max \{ x1, x2\}\} \ge \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

to test $H0: θ≤1$ versus $H1: θ>1$.

---

In here, I found the distribution of $X1+X2$ and $\max(X1, X2)$
after that, how can I figure out the power function of $C1$ and $C2$ and their sizes?
Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Use the definitions of size of a test  and power function to calculate them. Size of a test is the probability of type-I error; so calculate $P_{H_0}(C_1)$ and $P_{H_0}(C_2)$. And, for the power function, it is the probability of the complement of type-II error; so calculate $P_{H_1}(C_1)$ and $P_{H_1}(C_2)$.